# AJAX Ruby on Rails | partial not re-rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-ujs

Hi I'm fairly new to rails and am trying to implement AJAX in my Rails application.

The problem is that when I submit my form it seems like the create action is definitely called, as when I refresh the page the new element appears, but the table doesn't automatically refresh.

topics/show.html.erb relevant code:

```
<div class="row" id="toberefreshed">
  <%= render('show_partial', :locals => {:topic => @topic}) %>
</div>
```

topics/_show_partial.html.erb relevant code:

```
<table class = "opinionlist" align="center">
  <% opinions = @topic.opinions %>
  <% cons = opinions.select{|opinion| opinion.type_of == 'con'} %>
  <% pros = opinions.select{|opinion| opinion.type_of == 'pro'} %>
  <tr>
    <% pros.each do |pro|%>
      <td>
        <div class="article-body">
          <%= pro.content %>
        </div>
        <div class="article-meta-details">
          <small>
            Created by: <%= pro.user.username %>
            <%= time_ago_in_words(pro.created_at) %> ago,
          </small>
        </div>
      </td>
    <% end %>
    <% if pros.length < cons.length %>
      <% difference = cons.length - pros.length%>
      <% difference.times do %>
        <%= content_tag(:td) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <td><%= render 'opinions/form', opinion: Opinion.new, typeOf: "pro", :topic => @topic %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <% cons.each do |con|%>
      <td>
        <div class="article-body">
          <%= con.content %>
        </div>
        <div class="article-meta-details">
          <small>
            Created by: <%= con.user.username %>
            <%= time_ago_in_words(con.created_at) %> ago,
          </small>
        </div>
      </td>
    <% end %>
    <% if pros.length > cons.length %>
      <% difference = pros.length - cons.length %>
      <%  puts "DIFFERENCE: " + difference.to_s  %>
      <% difference.times do %>
        <%= content_tag(:td) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <td>
      <%= render 'opinions/form', opinion: Opinion.new, typeOf: "con", :topic => @topic %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

topics/updated_view.js.erb:

```
$("toberefreshed").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("topics/show_partial", :locals => {:topic => @opinion.topic})) %>");
```

opinions_controller.rb

```
class OpinionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @opinion = Opinion.new(opinion_params)
    @opinion.user = current_user
    @opinion.topic = Topic.find(params[:to_find_id])
    @opinion.type_of = params[:type_of]
    if @opinion.save
      flash[:success] = 'Opinion Added'
    else
      puts @opinion.errors.full_messages
      flash[:danger] = 'Opinion not Added'
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
  private
  def opinion_params
    params.require(:opinion).permit(:content)
  end
end
```

EDIT: opinions/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <%= form_for(opinion, :html=> {class:"form-horizontal", role:"form"}, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <%= f.text_area :content, rows:4, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Opinion" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'type_of', typeOf %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :to_find_id, @topic.id %>
      <% puts "ID: " + @topic.id.to_s %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <%= f.submit %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you so much for your help,
Raahil

Comment: Would you post the contents of `opinions/_form.html.erb`, please?

Comment: @ViktorNonov Yep, it should be there now. Sorry for forgetting it...

Comment: @Raail Jain, thank you, also `opinions/create.js.erb` will be helpful.

Comment: Rename updated_view.js.erb to create.js.erb

Comment: Should that be in the opinions folder? Or the topics folder?

Comment: It should be in opinions folder

Comment: So I did that and made the changes suggested by Moustafa below, it still doesn't seem to work... Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

In the `topics/_show_partial.html.erb`

replace

`<% opinions = @topic.opinions %>` in the second line

with

`<% opinions = topic.opinions %>`

You are passing the `topic` variable through locals in to the partial but you are calling `instance variable @topic` which doesn't exist when you call create method

Also change the following:

`<%= render 'opinions/form', opinion: Opinion.new, typeOf: "pro", :topic => @topic %>`

To

`<%= render 'opinions/form', opinion: Opinion.new, typeOf: "pro", :topic => topic %>`

---

And change

`<%= render 'opinions/form', opinion: Opinion.new, typeOf: "con", :topic => @topic %>`

To

`<%= render 'opinions/form', opinion: Opinion.new, typeOf: "con", :topic => topic %>`

---

So your In the `topics/_show_partial.html.erb` should look like the following:

```
<table class = "opinionlist" align="center">
  <% opinions = topic.opinions %>
  <% cons = opinions.select{|opinion| opinion.type_of == 'con'} %>
  <% pros = opinions.select{|opinion| opinion.type_of == 'pro'} %>
  <tr>
    <% pros.each do |pro|%>
      <td>
        <div class="article-body">
          <%= pro.content %>
        </div>
        <div class="article-meta-details">
          <small>
            Created by: <%= pro.user.username %>
            <%= time_ago_in_words(pro.created_at) %> ago,
          </small>
        </div>
      </td>
    <% end %>
    <% if pros.length < cons.length %>
      <% difference = cons.length - pros.length%>
      <% difference.times do %>
        <%= content_tag(:td) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <td><%= render 'opinions/form', opinion: Opinion.new, typeOf: "pro", :topic => topic %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <% cons.each do |con|%>
      <td>
        <div class="article-body">
          <%= con.content %>
        </div>
        <div class="article-meta-details">
          <small>
            Created by: <%= con.user.username %>
            <%= time_ago_in_words(con.created_at) %> ago,
          </small>
        </div>
      </td>
    <% end %>
    <% if pros.length > cons.length %>
      <% difference = pros.length - cons.length %>
      <%  puts "DIFFERENCE: " + difference.to_s  %>
      <% difference.times do %>
        <%= content_tag(:td) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <td>
      <%= render 'opinions/form', opinion: Opinion.new, typeOf: "con", :topic => topic %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

One Last thing that you can take as a recommendation:

You are building a lot of logic inside your views take for instance `topics/_show_partial.html.erb` you create lots of local variables inside the view. I would recommend using another approach like building all your variables in a layer between before the view like `presenters` check out this discussion about `rails presenters`

[What is the Rails Presenters folder for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458688/what-is-the-rails-presenters-folder-for)

`Views` should remain simple and free from logic as possible as you can

Comment: When I do that this happens: Showing /topics/_show_partial.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined local variable or method `topic' for #<#<Class:0x573ce40>:0xce8af88>
Did you mean?  @topic

Comment: no look at the docs to see how passing local variables to views https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables

Comment: Ok, so at this point my render statements look like this: render partial: "topics/show_partial", locals: {topic: @opinion.topic} Is this correct? I also renamed the js file to create.js.erb and moved it to opinions like Vasilisa suggested. It still doesn't seem to be replacing the content of my table, but I'm no longer getting the undefined local variable or method error.